# How to extrude a region after I selected extrude vertices only?

Tags: vertices

How to extrude a region after I selected extrude vertices only? I've tried changing 'Extrude>Vertices Only' to something else but I can't because I don't have another option than this one. Here's a screenshot with my problem:
[image]

This is how it was before choosing 'Vertices Only':
[image]

Comment: I noticed that you posted numerous questions today that are very very basic. I'd strongly advise you to take a look at the blender manual regarding basic modeling techniques. (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/index.html). We are glad to help beginners, but your rate of questions suggest no effort to find the solution yourself.

Comment: @yann Thanks for noticing me. Next time I'll try to search for the solution by myself for at least two hours before posting a question here.

Comment: When doing screenshots don't resize them down please (if you have really big monitor resize them to 1920x1080 resolution), they aren't easy to read.

Comment: @Mr Zak Thanks for telling me. I'll be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you extruded with *Vertices Only* there were created new vertices connected to existing vertices of the region:

[image]
<sub>Selected vertices moved away to show what actually is present after extruding</sub>

So you don't have any other option to extrude other than *Vertices Only* from here because technically there aren't any mesh elements selected except for vertices not forming neither faces nor edges. It's possible to extrude only another vertex from existing vertex (connected with an edge to something else or not).

To avoid creating wrong types of geometry delete these created vertices and select the face to extrude from it one more time. If you didn't move vertices after extruding there's an easy way to remove them, select all in that area and run <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*.